# SSLHandshakeException SSL handshake aborted

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

Some of my users are getting `SSLHandshakeException`, cannot reproduce it locally just seeing it in the Firebase console. Tried some of the other SO threads but they are all for devices running 4.4 and bellow.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7485342e08: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.doHandshake(NativeSsl.java:383)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:231)
```

MinSdk     - 21 
TargetSdk  - 28 
CompileSdk - 28 
OkHttp - 3.10.0

Any idea?